# Unexpected parse error json c#

Tags: c#, json

I am getting unexpected parse error while trying to read the below json value.This is the response that i get after calling an external API

```
"{
status: 201,
data: {
    booking_id: B2B-E51771039A176C,
    booking_amount: 5398.00,
    room_charges: 5398.00,
    meal_charges: 0.00,
    inclusion_charges: 600.00,
    taxes: 1133.58,
    status: Initiated
}
}"
```

I want to get the booking_id from the above json in a string.

Here is the model that i generated online

```
 public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("booking_id")]
        public string booking_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("booking_amount")]
        public string booking_amount { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("room_charges")]
        public string room_charges { get; set; }
         [JsonProperty("meal_charges")]
        public string meal_charges { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("inclusion_charges")]
        public string inclusion_charges { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("taxes")]
        public string taxes { get; set; }
         [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {

        public int status { get; set; }

        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is what i have used to convert

```
RootObject rootobj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonReplace);
```

Comment: How you are parsing this?

Comment: Can you also share the model you're using for deserialization?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you used for parsing, as well as the error message.

Comment: paste your above URL on **http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/** and see the results if this is valid JSON or not. And it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid JSON because in JSON a string value needs to be in quotes or else it will be treated as numeric. During deserialization the deserializer will attempt to treat the value as number and it will fail.

This is the valid json:

```
{
    status: 201,
    data: {
            booking_id: "B2B-E51771039A176C",
            booking_amount: 5398.00,
            room_charges: 5398.00,
            meal_charges: 0.00,
            inclusion_charges: 600.00,
            taxes: 1133.58,
            status:"Initiated" 
   }
}
```

Notice the quotations around `booking_id` and `status`.

This valid json will have a class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string booking_id { get; set; }
    public double booking_amount { get; set; }
    public double room_charges { get; set; }
    public double meal_charges { get; set; }
    public double inclusion_charges { get; set; }
    public double taxes { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Get the value like this:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var id = obj.data.booking_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.
Your booking_id value should have string in double quotes and status text also.

```
{
status: 201,
data: {
    booking_id: "B2B-E51771039A176C",
    booking_amount: 5398.00,
    room_charges: 5398.00,
    meal_charges: 0.00,
    inclusion_charges: 600.00,
    taxes: 1133.58,
    status: "Initiated"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that it is not valid, I think it's because of the `booking_id` and `status`. The data property for `booking_id` and `status` are not string, so I think it's the problem. You should pass it as string (with quotes):

```
"{
status: 201,
data: {
    booking_id: "B2B-E51771039A176C",
    booking_amount: 5398.00,
    room_charges: 5398.00,
    meal_charges: 0.00,
    inclusion_charges: 600.00,
    taxes: 1133.58,
    status: "Initiated"
}
}"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah the response i get is invalid have to contact the api provider to give a valid response in correct json format.Thanks :)

Comment: Good for you. Good luck with your development! :)